# How do you start running the program over again in gdb with 'target remote'?

Tags: embedded, gdb, debugging

When you're doing a usual gdb session on an executable file on the same computer, you can give the run command and it will start the program over again.

When you're running gdb on an embedded system, as with the command `target localhost:3210`, how do you start the program over again without quitting and restarting your gdb session?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for [Multi-Process Mode for gdbserver](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html) and [`set remote exec-file filename`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Configuration.html)

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to restart the application and still maintain your session.  A workaround is to set the PC back to the entry point of your program.  You can do this by either calling:

`jump function`

or

`set $pc=address`.

If you munged the arguments to `main` you may need set them up again.

Edit:

There are a couple of caveats with the above method that could cause problems.

- If you are in a multi-threaded program jumping to main will jump the current thread to main, all other threads remain.  If the current thread held a lock...then you have some problems.
- Memory leaks, if you program flow allocates some stuff during initialization then you just leaked a bunch of memory with the jump.
- Open files will still remain open.  If you mmap some files or an address, the call will most likely fail.

So, using jump isn't the same thing as restarting the program.

Comment: For a simple non multi-threaded app, jump was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

"jump _start" is the usual way.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you are running gdbserver on the embedded system.

You can ask it to restart your program instead of exiting with [target extended-remote](http://web.archive.org/web/20090605020212/http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_19.html)

Comment: Helpful, didn't now about target extended-mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For me the method described in [21.2 Sample GDB session startup](http://openocd.org/doc/html/GDB-and-OpenOCD.html#Sample-GDB-session-startup) works great. When I enter `monitor reset halt` later at the “(gdb)” prompt the target hardware is reset and I can re-start the application with `c` (= continue).

The `load` command can be omitted between the runs because there is no need to flash the program again and again.

Answer (score 3):

**Step-by-step procedure**

Remote:

```
# pwd contains cross-compiled ./myexec
gdbserver --multi :1234
```

Local:

```
# pwd also contains the same cross-compiled ./myexec
gdb -ex 'target extended-remote 192.168.0.1:1234' \
    -ex 'set remote exec-file ./myexec' \
    --args ./myexec arg1 arg2
(gdb) r
[Inferior 1 (process 1234) exited normally]
(gdb) r
[Inferior 1 (process 1235) exited normally]
(gdb) monitor exit
```

Tested in Ubuntu 14.04.

It is also possible to pass CLI arguments to the program as:

```
gdbserver --multi :1234 ./myexec arg1 arg2
```

and the `./myexec` part removes the need for `set remote exec-file ./myexec`, but this has the following annoyances:

- undocumented: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21981
- does not show on `show args` and does not persist across restarts: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21980

Pass environment variables and change working directory without restart: [How to modify the environment variables and working directory of gdbserver --multi without restarting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149858/how-to-modify-the-environment-variables-of-gdbserver-without-restarting-it)

Answer (score 2):

If you are running regular gdb you can type 'run' shortcut 'r' and gdb asks you if you wish to restart the program

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jump` gdb command. For that, you can check your `startup` script.
My `startup script` has a symbol.

```
    .section  .text.Reset_Handler
  .weak  Reset_Handler
  .type  Reset_Handler, %function
Reset_Handler:  
   ldr   r0, =_estack
   mov   sp, r0          /* set stack pointer */
```

I wanted to jump to start. That's why I used:

```
jump Reset_Handler
```

Answer (score 0):

On EFM32 Happy Gecko none of the suggestions would work for me, so here is what I have learned from the documentation on integrating GDB into the Eclipse environment.

```
(gdb) mon reset 0
(gdb) continue
(gdb) continue
```

This puts me in the state that I would have expected when hitting reset from the IDE.