# How to set up the Eclipse for remote C debugging with gdbserver?

Tags: c, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am pretty new to Eclipse. Trying to set up to do remote debugging.

Here is situation, I am connecting to remote machine running Linux, I am running Windows.

1) I have installed all the necessary tool for Eclipse, and was able to connect to Linux machine.

2) Remote machine has `gdbserver`

```
linux1[1]% gdbserver
Usage:  gdbserver [OPTIONS] COMM PROG [ARGS ...]
        gdbserver [OPTIONS] --attach COMM PID
        gdbserver [OPTIONS] --multi COMM

COMM may either be a tty device (for serial debugging), or
HOST:PORT to listen for a TCP connection.

Options:
  --debug               Enable debugging output.
```

Do I need to configure anything in `gdbserver` ???

3) What else should I configure in Eclipse ? for remote debugging ?

4) Does it matter that my GDB version is different from remote Machine GDB ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote debugging C++ applications with Eclipse CDT/RSE/RDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685104/remote-debugging-c-applications-with-eclipse-cdt-rse-rdt)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gdbserver` needs more arguments. For example, say `gdbserver localhost:1337 yourprogram yourprogramarguments` and keep it running.

Then, in Eclipse, create a new debug configuration for a "C/C++ Application". On the main tab, on the bottom, choose `GDB (GSF) Remote System Process Launcher` as launcher. On the debugger tab, choose `gdbserver Debugger` as the debugger. Under connection, say `TCP` as connection type and give `localhost:1337` as address. When you launch the configuration, you may control the remote `gdb` by entering commands into the console.

Comment: There is no "GDB(GSF) Remote System Process Launcher" option in the main tab in "C/C++ Application" under debug configuration... :-(

Answer (score 12):

**CLI sanity check**

Before you do anything, make sure you:

- cross compile the application correctly and that it runs. You don't necessarily need to do this using Eclipse.
- get GDB remote debugging working properly from the command line. This may help: [How do you start running the program over again in gdb with 'target remote'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75255/how-do-you-start-running-the-program-over-again-in-gdb-with-target-remote/44161527#44161527)

This answer supposes that you can do on the development board:

```
sudo apt-get install gdbserver
gdbserver :1234 path/to/executable
```

And on host:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb \
  -ex "target remote board-hostname:1234" \
  -ex "file path/to/cross/compiled/executable" \
  -ex 'tb main' \
  -ex c
```

and then step debug everything correctly.

**Eclipse setup**

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04 host, Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0 (downloaded from website), `gdbserver` 7.12, `aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb` 7.6.

I have successfully used all of the following methods:

- manual
- automatic

  - password auth
  - public key auth

**Manual**

With this method, we have to launch `gdbserver` on the target before running debug on Eclipse.

Pro: dispenses configuring SSH connections through Eclipse to allow Eclipse to run `gdbserver`, which is another possible point of failure.

Con: you have to relaunch `gdbserver` every time debugging starts. This could be overcome if Eclipse understood `gdbserver --multi`, but I don't think it does?

Due to its simplicity, I recommend that you get this method working first.

Open the debug configurations, then create a new "C / C++ Remote Application".

Under the tab "Main":

- select the "Name", "Project" and "C/C++ Application" as usual for a local debug
- at the bottom launcher, click "Select other", check "Use configuration specific settings" and pick "GDB (DSF) Manual Remote Debugging Launcher"

  Why we do this: the automatic launcher first connects to the board with SSH and launches the `gdbserver` for you.

  [image]

Under the tab "Debugger":

- "GDB debugger": same as used from CLI on host, `aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb` for this example
- Sub-tab "Connection": set hostname and port as passed to the host on CLI  (`board-hostname` and `1234`)

  [image]

  [image]

Finally, manually launch `gdbserver` on the target just as we did from the CLI:

```
gdbserver :1234 path/to/executable
```

and start the debugger from Eclipse normally.

You have to restart `gdbserver` every time you terminate the program.

**Automatic with password auth**

This is the best method for development boards, which have fixed publicly known passwords.

It connects to the target with SSH and a password, and launches `gdbserver` on the target automatically every time, which is super convenient!

Target `gdbserver` stdout goes to the Eclipse "Console" window, which further reduces window switching.

In Eclipse set:

- work around the "Secure storage was unable to save the master password" bug as explained at: [How to solve "Secure storage was unable to save the master password" in Eclipse CDT remote application with SSH password debug connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658574/how-to-solve-secure-storage-was-unable-to-save-the-master-password-in-eclipse/45658575#45658575)
- set the launcher to: "Automatic Remote Debugging Launcher"
- set "Remote Absolute File Path 
  for C/C++ Application" to `/root/path/to/project/path/to/executable`
- "Connection", "New", and choose "Password based authentication"

**Automatic with public key**

Very similar to the password authentication, except that you must go to: "Connection", "New", and choose "Public key based authentication"

Pros:

- overcomes the "Secure storage was unable to save the master password" if you have an unencrypted private key (unsafe, but fine for devboards)
- for servers, you likely have already setup the public key

Cons:

- key setup may hurt the first time
- must redo key setup whenever devboard is nuked

so I would prefer this method for servers.

SSH can connect without a password if you:

- set `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the target to contain the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from the host
- have a non encrypted private key on host, which bypasses our password woes
- set pesky folder permissions correctly: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication

Before using this method, make sure that your authorized keys work from the command line, i.e. you should now be able to do:

```
ssh user@host
```

without typing any password.

Comment: It seems that now in 4.8, Eclipse Photon systematically tries to start gdbserver by itself through a telnet connection.

Answer (score 4):

**Update for Eclipse 2019-03**

In eclipse 2019, the above steps didn't work, because Eclipse has changed the layout of the configuration in "C/C++ Remote Application".

Updates of @Ciro post:

The following steps worked with me:
Under "Debug Configurations"
Under "C / C++ Remote Application"
Under the tab "Main":

- select the "Connection" ==> "Remote Host".
- select "New" , "SSH" (In my case) , then enter the configuration for your remote target machine.
- in "Remote Absolute File Path for C/C++ Application:" set the path of the application in the target/remote device.

Under the tab "Debugger":

- Sub-tab "Connection" has been removed.
- New sub-tab "Gdbserver Settings" has been added.
- Configure "Gdbserver path:" to point to the path of gdbserver.  In my case it was "/usr/bin/gdbserver"
- Configure port number

These are the only changes I made so that the previous answer works with me.