# How to set gdb debugger connection?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-indigo

The instructions [here](https://www.ridgerun.com/developer/wiki/index.php/Debug_and_Profiling_Guide#Create_debug_configuration) show how to create a debug configuration but seem to be based on a different version of eclipse. How is the gdb debugger connection (TCP/IP address and Port number) configured in eclipse-indigo? I see `Network Connections` in `Edit Configuration -> Configure Workspace Settings -> General...` but no way to add TCP/IP address and Port number.

Comment: Generic howto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038760/how-to-set-up-the-eclipse-for-remote-c-debugging-with-gdbserver/45608937#45608937

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instructions are still mostly valid, I think.

- "Run" menu => "Debug Configurations..." option
- "C/C++ Attach to application" option => "New" contextual menu option
- "Debugger" tab => Debugger: "gdbserver" option => "Connection" tab

[image: gdbserver]