# Eclipse remote debugging arm-linux library

Tags: eclipse, gdb, embedded-linux, gdbserver

I am running:

- Eclipse 3.8.1 (Build id: deb build).
- On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in a VM and UbuntuMATE 16.04 LTS on target Raspberry Pi 3.
- gdb-multiarch`(architecture set to arm in .gdbinit) locally and`gdbserver` on the target.

Cross compilation and remote deployment is successful. However, there appears to be some library issue when I run on the remote target. Output from `gdb-multiarch` below (superfluous text removed):

> GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11-0ubuntu1) 7.11 Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software 
>   Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
>   http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html This GDB was configured as 
>   "x86_64-linux-gnu".  
>    
>    
>   Program stopped.  0x76fd7a40 in ?? () from 
>   /home/fred/raspberrypi/rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.23.so

Execution stops at `main`. However, it doesn't appear to stop due to a breakpoint. The stop appears to be the result of some library issue possibly and unresolved symbol (or something more serious) resulting in the `??`.

I have `set sysroot` in the `.gdbinit` file to indicate where the shared libraries can be found. The StepIn, StepOut icons are hi-lighted in Eclipse, and I can read ARM registers if I press pause and see which core is being used to run the process (with process ID)!

After further resume & pause operations a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) occurs:

> Program stopped. 0x76fe2e92 in ?? () from 
>   /home/fred/raspberrypi/rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.23.so 
>   
>   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x76fd905e in ?? 
>   () from 
>   /home/fred/raspberrypi/rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.23.so
>
> Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. The 
>   program no longer exists.

Any ideas? (I am very much new to Linux as it probably shows.)

Thanks for the questions which have resulted in further exploration below:

In Eclipse I started GDB by selecting `Debug Configuration` and then choosing the remote configuration that I had set up.

The code is very simple, consisting of a stream operator to output some text and then a loop, however it is never reached. I think I have just managed to reproduce the issue from the command line. Incidentally I started the target going first. (Again superfluous text was removed for clarity.)

```
gdb-multiarch Hello_Raspberry_Pi

Reading symbols from Hello_Raspberry_Pi...done.
The target architecture is assumed to be arm
(gdb) target remote ubuntumate-pi
(gdb) target remote 192.168.0.12:2345
Remote debugging using 192.168.0.12:2345
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initialisers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
0x76fd7a40 in ?? ()
(gdb) set architecture arm
The target architecture is assumed to be arm
(gdb) set sysroot /home/fred/raspberrypi/rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initialisers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
(gdb)
```

The target side behaved as would be expected:

```
fred@UbuntuMATE-Pi:~/Hello_Raspberry_Pi$ gdbserver 192.168.0.7:2345 Hello_Raspberry_Pi
Process Hello_Raspberry_Pi created; pid = 17363
Listening on port 2345
Remote debugging from host 192.168.0.7
```

So perhaps `Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.` is a big clue?

It would appear that I had defined `Shared Libraries` incorrectly. When I deleted this setting something closer to expected behaviour occurred. As shown below, however I there is still a warning that I would like to remove:

```
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initialisers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
0x76fd7a40 in ?? ()

Breakpoint 2, main () at ../src/Hello_Raspberry_Pi.cpp:18
18            cout << "I'm in the While loop and the value of variable i is: " << i << endl;

Breakpoint 1, main () at ../src/Hello_Raspberry_Pi.cpp:20
20            usleep(1000000); //wait for 1 seconds
```

So now Eclipse does breakpoint at main and permit stepping - finally!

Comment: How did you start gdb? What did it load/what are you trying to debug? Can you reproduce this running gdb from command line? What's the effect of running application without gdb?

Comment: This forum thread might be useful: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/634692/

Comment: @dbrank0 thanks for the thought stimulating input.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038760/how-to-set-up-the-eclipse-for-remote-c-debugging-with-gdbserver/45608937#45608937

Answer (score 2):

I also faced problems similar to this, getting segmentation fault from ld.so. Did the following steps to fix it.

1. Install libc6-dbg package in both sysroot and target.
2. create a folder /lib/.debug in both sysroot and target.
3. copy  /usr/lib/debug/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.23.so to /lib/.debug in both sysroot and target.