# How to solve "Secure storage was unable to save the master password" in Eclipse CDT remote application with SSH password debug connection?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to debug a C program remotely with Eclipse and `gdbserver`.

I have managed to make both the manual and public key SSH authentication work with Eclipse as described at: [Remote debugging C++ applications with Eclipse CDT/RSE/RDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685104/remote-debugging-c-applications-with-eclipse-cdt-rse-rdt/45658783#45658783)

However, if I try to create a connection with SSH password, creation fails a few error popups appear, the first of which is:

```
Secure storage was unable to save the master password
```

The first two lines of the stack trace are:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get DBus session bus: Could not connect: Connection refused
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.linux.LinuxPasswordProvider.saveMasterPassword(Native Method)
```

Other exceptions I got are:

```
No password provided.
```

and:

```
Unable to locate secure storage module
```

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04 host and Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0 downloaded from the Eclipse website.

Some possibly related issues:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329615
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429678
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329615
- https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/212
- https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/ptp-user/msg03178.html

Answer (score 26):

Go to Window > Preferences > Secure storage and *uncheck* "Linux Integration (64 bit)", leaving "UI Prompt" as the only checked option.

Likely Eclipse was trying to integrate with some native password provider, and the integration is bogged. TODO: understand precisely why.

Now, the next time I try to create the connection with password, a popup appears asking me to set a "Master password". I do that, and everything works.

[image]

Comment: I tried several other solutions, this was the one that worked.  I believe w/ Linux Integration, it means any person who logs in to the system can access secure storage.

Comment: Linux Integration throws  "Unable to find default secret collection" if not installed.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a lot