# How to prepare eclipse setting for remote debugging

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdbserver

I am trying to debug an application which runs on another target(remote) machine. I can run this application on remote machine and debug my code under admin user privileges. But I need to start gdbserver and my application under root privilages to understand exact behavior so I couldn't start gdbserver and application with root. Is there anybody can help me?

Comment: could be a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038760/how-to-set-up-the-eclipse-for-remote-c-debugging-with-gdbserver

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it with recent Eclipse version but here are my notes for this.
Not sure of all menu/tab names (I'm not working with English version)

on target you must run gdb server specifying port

```
target #  gdbserver :3210 ./mytest
```

on dev platform

eclipse config: (/ means sub-menu or tab except if quoted)

```
 run / 'debug configuration' / 'C/C++ remote application' / 

 main-tab / set : Manual remote debugging (lower part)
 debugger-tab / main-tab / set gdb debugger: 
 debugger-tab / connection-tab / set: tcp , ip(target ip) , port(3210)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your answer but I couldn't understand which part is regarding with root privilages?

Comment: check around:   gdbserver --wrapper env