# How to restart QEMU user mode programs from the GDB stub as in gdbserver --multi?

Tags: qemu

[How to single step ARM assembler in GDB on Qemu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590155/how-to-single-step-arm-assembler-in-gdb-on-qemu) teaches us about QEMU user mode GDB step debugging and [How do you start running the program over again in gdb with 'target remote'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75255/how-do-you-start-running-the-program-over-again-in-gdb-with-target-remote) teaches us that `--multi` allows you to re-run a program from inside GDB directly with `run`.

Does the QEMU user mode GDB stub, e.g. `-g 1234` implement such `--multi`-like functionality, so I can `run` the program from inside `gdb` multiple times and keep my breakpoints around?

Answer (score 3):

QEMU doesn't implement this, I'm afraid. If you want to restart the guest binary you need to restart the gdb session too.