# What is the intended recompile/debug workflow with gdbserver?

Tags: gdbserver

I'm cross-compiling for an embedded linux target and debugging using gdbserver. On the target I run `gdbserver :2000 /home/root/demo` and on the host I run `gdb-multiarch` followed by `target remote 10.24.0.236:2000` to connect to the server (as per [this tutorial](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/04/gdbserver-example)).

Everytime I recompile my program I `kill` the program from the gdb client, recompile, restart the server and run `target remote 10.24.0.236:2000` again.

Must I restart the server each time I recompile?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use "multi process mode" by running `target extended-remote 10.24.0.236:2000` instead of `target remote 10.24.0.236:2000`.

Now running `kill` from the host stops the program without stopping the server. The program can now be recompiled. Running `run` from the host starts the new program (assuming it has the same filename as before).

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75255/7962446). I've left my question up because I interpreted the original question as asking how to restart the same program (without necessarily loading a new version from disk).